# Error when running LecoS Plugin in QGIS (Query raster values- Point): NameError: name 'QMessageBox' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, importerror, nameerror

This error message comes up when I try to run the LecoS Plugin in QGIS for querying landcover raster values at coordinate points of Bluetit birds on my map:

```
QGIS version: 3.32.3-Lima
QGIS code revision: 67d46100b5
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.7.2
GEOS version: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.0, September 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.5.5 (git-version: 24f78d)
Algorithm started at: 2023-12-11T09:23:26
Algorithm 'Query raster values (Points)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'OUTPUT_FILE' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'POINT' : 'C:/Users/chiar/Documents/FolkestoneData/bluetitreproj.shp|layername=bluetitreproj', 'RASTER' : 'C:/Users/chiar/Documents/FolkestoneData/LCKent.vrt' }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/chiar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LecoS\lecos_sextantealgorithms.py", line 918, in processAlgorithm
classes, array = lcs.f_landcover(str(inputFilename)) # Get array from band 1
File "C:\Users/chiar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LecoS\landscape_statistics.py", line 148, in f_landcover
QMessageBox.warning( QDialog(),"LecoS: Warning","Multiband Rasters not implemented yet")
NameError: name 'QMessageBox' is not defined

Execution failed after 0.61 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Query raster values (Points)' finished
```

I tried following the advice on this site to paste this into my imports section: `from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox`

But the error persists!

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
processing.run("lecos:queryraster", {'RASTER':'C:/Users/chiar/Documents/FolkestoneData/LCKent.vrt','BAND':1,'POINT':'C:/Users/chiar/Documents/FolkestoneData/bluetitreproj.shp|layername=bluetitreproj','OUTPUT_FILE':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 176, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 70, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/chiar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LecoS\lecos_sextantealgorithms.py", line 918, in processAlgorithm
    classes, array = lcs.f_landcover(str(inputFilename)) # Get array from band 1
  File "C:\Users/chiar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LecoS\landscape_statistics.py", line 148, in f_landcover
    QMessageBox.warning( QDialog(),"LecoS: Warning","Multiband Rasters not implemented yet")
NameError: name 'QMessageBox' is not defined
```

I also tried to import QMessageBox like this: from PyQt5.QtGui import QMessageBox

but it creates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QMessageBox' from 'PyQt5.QtGui' (C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd)
```

I'm quite new to QGIS and my computer is limited in computing capacity.